# Finding the collection length in firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have over 20k objects in my Firebase Realtime Database. I now need to take out all these objects and do stuff to them. The problem is the server runs out of memory every time I do it. This is my current code:

```
sendEmail.get('/:types/:message', cors(), async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(5);
    const types = JSON.parse(req.params.types);
    console.log('types', types);
    let recipients = [];
    let mails = [];
    if (types.includes('students')) {
        console.log(1);
        const tmpUsers = await admin.database().ref('Users').orderByChild('student').equalTo(true).once('value').then(r => r.val()).catch(e => console.log(e));
        recipients = recipients.concat(tmpUsers);
    }
    if (types.includes('solvers')) {
        console.log(2);
        let tmpUsers = await admin.database().ref('Users').orderByChild('userType').equalTo('person').once('value').then(r => r.val()).catch(e => console.log(e));
        tmpUsers = tmpUsers.concat(arrayFromObject(await admin.database().ref('Users').orderByChild('userType').equalTo('company').once('value').then(r => r.val()).catch(e => console.log(e))));
        recipients = recipients.concat(tmpUsers);
    }
});
```

So I have two options. Streaming or limiting the response with `startAt` and `endAt`. But to limit the responses I need to know how many objects exactly I have. And to do this I need to download the whole collection... You see my problem now. How can I learn how many documents I have, without downloading the whole collection?

Comment: The trick is to use [`limitToFirst`/`limitToLast`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#limit-queries) combined with `startAt`/`endAt`. For example, you can perform the first query with `limitToFirst(100)`, then obtain the last key from this returned list and use that with: `startAt(key)` and another `limitToFirst(100)`. There is a simple example available in the documentation discussing [range queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#range-queries) that hints at this. I'll see if I can draw up a node.js example.

Comment: I'd appreciate an example. I think I see what you're going for, but I'm not sure I fully understand

Comment: I'll try to whip one up. Thinking about this a little more though: if it's the Cloud Function that's timing out when dealing with large datasets, you could [increase the function's timeout and memory allocation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation) instead.

Comment: I already tried that. 2GB are not enough. I was shocked myself

Comment: I'm actually not sure if paginating will help now that I've written an example. I'll post my answer anyway, but you might have to split the data processing across multiple function invocations instead.

Comment: It's worth a shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try paginating your query by combining [`limitToFirst`/`limitToLast`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#limit-queries) and `startAt`/`endAt`.

For example, you could perform the first query with `limitToFirst(1000)`, then obtain the last key from this returned list and use that with `startAt(key)` and another `limitToFirst(1000)`, repeating until you reach the end of the collection.

In node.js, it might look something like this (*untested code*):

```
let recipients = [];

let tmpUsers = next();
recipients = filter(recipients, tmpUsers);

// startAt is inclusive, so when this reaches the last result there will only be 1
while (tmpUsers.length>1) {
    let lastKey = tmpUsers.slice(-1).pop().key;
    tmpUsers = next(lastKey);
    if (tmpUsers.length>1) { // Avoid duplicating last result
        recipients = filter(recipients, tmpUsers);
    }
}

async function next(startAt) {
    if (!startAt) {
        return await admin.database().ref('Users')
                .orderByKey()
                .limitToFirst(1000)
                .once('value').then(r => r.val()).catch(e => console.log(e));
    } else {
        return await admin.database().ref('Users')
                .orderByKey()
                .startAt(startAt)
                .limitToFirst(1000)
                .once('value').then(r => r.val()).catch(e => console.log(e));
    }
}

function filter(array1, array2) {
    // TODO: Filter the results here as we can't combine orderByChild/orderByKey
    return array1.concat(array2);
}
```

The problem with this is that you won't be able to use database-side filtering, so you'd need to filter the results manually, which might make things worse, depending on how many items you need to keep in the `recipients` variable at a time.

Another option would be to process them in batches (of 1000 for example), pop them from the `recipients` array to free up resources and then move onto the next batch. It does depend entirely on what actions you need to perform on the objects, and you'll need to weigh up whether it's actually necessary to process (and keep in memory) the entire result set in one go.

Comment: It will keep going until the database only returns 1 result or less (`while (tmpUsers.length>1)`) which means it's reached the end of the list. This is because [`startAt`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Query#startAt) is inclusive, so returning 1 results means it's reached the end. At least, that's the idea, if my code works!

Comment: Ooook. That makes sense. I'll take a look at it

Comment: Great answer @Grimthorr!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to know the size of the collection to process them by batch.

You can do it by ordering them by key, limiting to 1000 or so, and then on next batch start the last key of the first batch.

If you still want to know how to get the size of the collection, the only good way is to maintain the size of collection in separate node and keep it updated when the collection is updated.